# PHP - get min and max values of numbers with special difference to each other

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have a problem getting the min and max values from a row of numbers with a special difference of 1800 in it. For better understanding, I want to give you the following example:

```
array(0,1800,3600,5400,7200,12600,14400,16200,23400,25200);
```

The special difference for my row of numbers is 1800. When a number has an exactly difference of 1800 to the next number, they are numbers of the same row. If not, they are numbers of another row. So I need a function which will produce the following output for the array mentioned above:

- Output 1: min value 0, max value 7200
- Output 2: min value 12600, max value 16200
- Output 3: min value 23400, max value 25200

I hope you understand my question. Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried, we will help you with your code, not code as a whole

Comment: This is pretty simple logic so please show us what you have done so far so we can point you in the right direction

Comment: I am sorry, I have only sketched a logical solution on a paper. There wasnt any code in PHP yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alway better to show some of the code you have tried so far. 
However here is a very short code example I put together.

```
$lists       = [];
$special     = 1800;
$array       = [0, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 12600, 14400, 16200, 23400, 25200];
$currentList = [];
foreach ($array as $number) {
    if (empty($currentList)) {
        $currentList[] = $number;
    } else {
        $last =(end($currentList) + $special);
        if ($number === $last) {
            $currentList[] = $number;
        } else {
            $lists[]     = $currentList;
            $currentList = [$number];
        }
    }
}
$lists[] = $currentList;
var_dump($lists);
```

This will output the following array, which could be transformed in the output you want.

```
array (size=3)   0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1800
      2 => int 3600
      3 => int 5400
      4 => int 7200   1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 12600
      1 => int 14400
      2 => int 16200   2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 23400
      1 => int 25200
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Exactly, what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function to iterate your input and add the values to an array of rows

```
function getRows($input, $specialDifference) {
    $rows = array();
    $newRow = true;
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($input); $index++) {
        if ($newRow) {
            $rows[] = array();
            $newRow = false;
        }
        $rows[count($rows) - 1][]= $input[$index];
        $newRow = ((count($input) > $index + 1) && ($input[$index + 1] - $input[$index] !== $specialDifference));
    }
    return $rows;
}
```